# Emacs Prelude - Electric indentation

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I am trying to get electric indentation working in prelude.

In the .emacs.d/personal/personal.el file I have added the below

```lisp
;;; package --- Summary
;;; adding indent for python and binding for python-django
;;; Code:
(electric-indent-mode +1)
;;; Commentary:

;;; package --- Summary
;;; adding indent for python and binding for python-django
;;; Code:
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x j") 'python-django-open-project)
;;; Commentary:

(provide 'personal)\n
;;; personal.el ends here
```

electric should work as I got it from bbatsov's site.[electric-indent](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/03/29/automatic-electric-indentation/)

I notic however that even ctrl-j isn't working to indent. how do I fix this?

EDIT error from personal.el

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable n)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-827116> nil "/home/sayth/.emacs.d/personal/personal.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 327
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/sayth/.emacs.d/personal/personal.el" "/home/sayth/.emacs.d/personal/personal.el" nil nil)
  load("/home/sayth/.emacs.d/personal/personal.el")
  mapc(load ("/home/sayth/.emacs.d/personal/personal.el"))
  (progn (message "Loading personal configuration files in %s..." prelude-personal-dir) (mapc (quote load) (directory-files prelude-personal-dir (quote t) "^[^#].*el$")))
  (if (file-exists-p prelude-personal-dir) (progn (message "Loading personal configuration files in %s..." prelude-personal-dir) (mapc (quote load) (directory-files prelude-personal-dir (quote t) "^[^#].*el$"))))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/sayth/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4738
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/sayth/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/sayth/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/sayth/.emacs.d/init" t t)   #[0 "\205\262
```

Answer (score 1):

`electric-indent-mode` seems to work just fine when I test in Emacs 24.3.50. You should keep in mind that it remaps <kbd>C-j</kbd> to `electric-indent-just-newline`. It simply inserts a newline, without any auto-indentation.

This makes a lot of sense, as the <kbd>RET</kbd> auto-indents when the mode is enabled. I seem to recall it was buggy in older versions of Emacs, so I'd suggest taking a look at `emacs-snapshot` if you want to use it.

Comment: I have emacs 24.3.1 running, ctrl-j and electric works in vanilla emacs, I am only getting the error in preude. I have updated post with personal.el but now I receive this error. edited in post

Comment: Remove the `\n` from `(provide 'personal)\n`.